# Activity.onTouchEvent isn't called after returning from background

Tags: android, android-activity, touch

On my activity I override the `onTouchEvent` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MyActivity.onTouchEvent");

    ...

    return false;
}
```

That works as expected until the app goes to the background, when it returns that method isn't being called anymore.

To try and understand what's going on I added a touch listener to the root view:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d((TAG, "content.onTouch view: " + view);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the same output for both scenarios, before and after going to background, in both cases the view it prints is the same: `android:id/content`.

Since that's not "my view", I also tried:

```
((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d((TAG, "content.onTouch view: " + view);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which acts the same in both cases (just the view it prints is the main layout in my xml file).

Any idea why the `OnTouchListener` is called even after returning from background but the `onTouchEvent` isn't?

There aren't any other views that I could find that return true for the touch event, and the printing of the view in the listener also proves that.

I've been trying to figure it out for the last two days now but to no avail. Would love to get any kind of a clue or direction.
Thanks.

Comment: I have tried this but onTouchEvent is working here even after app comes from background. Can you give exact code with return type so i can try that ?

Comment: I created a new project with only an activity and it indeed works well.
I can't really post any more code as I have no clue what might be relevant to the issue and the file is a HUGE one as it's one of our main activities. I guess I'm asking for possible reasons for it to happen?

Comment: I would speculate that your view doesn't get re-initialized after coming back from background... maybe you placed the initialization of your view in onCreate() instead of onResume() or something like that... the problem is obviously not the touch event, but the absence of the view.